# Boost Karma for a boost::variant containing a custom class

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I'd like to investigate `boost::spirit::karma::generate` as a replacement for `std::stringstream` for a `boost::variant` containing, apart from familiar types such as `int` and `double`, one or more custom classes (e.g. `A`).  However I'm unable to even compile the code once I include one or more custom classes in the variant.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

struct A {
    double d;
    explicit A(const double d) : d(d) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A const& m) {
        return os << "{" << m.d << "}";
    }
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(A, d)

using Variant = boost::variant<int, double, A>;

void test_stringstream(const Variant &v) {
    std::stringstream os;
    os << v;
    std::cout << os.str() << std::endl;
}

void test_karma(const Variant &v) {
    std::string str;
    boost::spirit::karma::generate(std::back_inserter(str), v);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    A a(double(1.0));
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    test_stringstream(Variant(a));
    test_karma(Variant(a));
}
```

I'd expect the output:

```
{1}
{1}
{1}
```

The error output begins with

```
mpl_iterator.hpp:45:24: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'boost::fusion::mpl_iterator<boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::l_item<mpl_::long_<1>, A, boost::mpl::l_end>>>::deref<boost::fusion::mpl_iterator<boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::l_item<mpl_::long_<1>, A, boost::mpl::l_end>>>>::type' (aka 'A')
                return type();
```

Apart from custom classes, I'd also like to enquire how one could make Enums 'streamable' as it were via `boost::spirit::karma::generate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message informs you that A is not default-constructible. It's a long type expression, but helpfully summarized it for you: `(aka 'A')`.

Adding a default value for `d` fixes it:

```
explicit A(double d = {}) : d(d) {}
```

Now with

```
std::cout << "iostream:     " << a << std::endl;
std::cout << "stringstream: "; test_stringstream(Variant(a));
std::cout << "karma:        "; test_karma(Variant(a));
```

You'd see ([Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0dbf543a147c7a98))

```
iostream:     {1}
stringstream: {1}
karma:
```

You didn't pass any karma expression to `generate`. Let's add:

```
void test_karma(const Variant& v) {
    namespace k = boost::spirit::karma;
    std::string str;
    k::generate(std::back_inserter(str), k::stream, v);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Now you get the same output. Note that the Fusion adaptation is completely unnecessary here, don't actually ever deal with `A` in your karma expression. It will effectively amount to the `stringstream` implementation, but with extra steps, so it will be slower.

### Demo

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f14165036ef5e96)

Prints

```
iostream:     {1}
stringstream: {1}
karma:        {1}
```

### Suggestions

I'd suggest using Boost `lexical_cast` here. It's almost guaranteed to be faster and certainly less ... clumsy:

[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc214fcf38c0bbe9)

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    explicit A(double d = {}) : d(d) {}

  private:
    double d;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A const& m) {
        return os << "{" << m.d << "}";
    }
};

using Variant = boost::variant<int, double, A>;

int main() {
    Variant vv[]{42, 3.14, A(1.0)};
    for (Variant a : vv)
        std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(a) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
42
3.14
{1}
```

Comment: I had a hunch you'd answer @sehe. Excellent and considered answer --as usual.